# embed small image over big image using HTML and plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I would like to embed small image over big image using HTML and plain javascript. It is working in Chrome and Firefox. But it is not working in IE 8. I used z-index:-1 as suggested in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp. Can anybody help with code snippet?

Please find the example code snippet, which is working in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and not working in IE8

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Image over Image</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadIMG(){
        var backgroundIMG = document.getElementById("bigIMG");
        var boundObject = backgroundIMG.getBoundingClientRect();

        var img = document.getElementById("smallIMG");
        img.style.top = (boundObject.top + (boundObject.height * 0.2))+"px";
        img.style.left = (boundObject.left  + (boundObject.width * 0.2))+"px";
        img.style.height = (boundObject.height * 0.6)+"px";
        img.style.width = (boundObject.width *0.6)+"px";
        img.style.position = "absolute";
        img.style.display = "inline";

    }
</script>
</head>
<body onclick="loadIMG();">
<center><h1>Image on Image</h1>
<h6>Click on the page to embed small image on big image</h6></center>
<img id="bigIMG" src="http://www.sxc.hu/pic/m/t/tu/tulsaeupho/1206951_blue_flowers_splatter_and_swirls_background_set_1.jpg">
<img id="smallIMG" src="http://i52.photobucket.com/albums/g14/1kevinm/small_unittus_sm_icon.png" style="display:none">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code(non-working in IE) that you have now.

Comment: Create a small snippet in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and post here

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd put the style for bigIMG and smallIMG in a separate CSS file like style.css containing

```
#bigIMG {
  z-index: -1;
  posistion:absolute;
}
#smallIMG {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
```

note that both the images have position:absolute and the bigIMG has z-index:-1 so that it will be placed behind the other content.

Now in the HEAD element of your html, include your style.css like so:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">`

Then try to adjust the 'top' and 'left' parameters in the css to correctly position the images. You can use chrome's Element inspector to manually type coordinates on the fly